# Как правильно обрабатывать столкновения движущейся окружности и нескольких линий?

Tags: алгоритм, разработка-игр, физика

Есть работающий алгоритм, обрабатывающий столкновения движушейся окружности и линии (сегмента линии). Столкновения определяются и разрешаются корректно. Но если окружность "одновременно" касается 2 линий (т. е. очень быстро касается то одной, то другой) - возникает нереалистичная ситуация. Причем, корректная для каждой пары "окружность-линия".

Окружность "падает" на две, расположенные под углом линии (изображение 1). В момент контакта со второй линией она начинает двигаться вниз как и должна. Но в определенный момент останавливается, не касаясь другой линии (изображение 3).
Похоже, разрешение столкновений в этом кадре происходит следующим образом.
Окружность выталкивается в сторону первой линии и контактирует с ней (4). Потом выталкивается в сторону второй линии (5), контактирует с ней и вторая линия выталкивает ее так же, но без контакта с первой (6). Кадр завершается, окружность видна на экране в этой позиции. Потом эта же ситуация повторяется снова и снова и окружность "зависает".
Как можно исправить? Чтобы окружность скатилась в самый низ и уперлась в обе линии? Если угол достаточно острый - так и происходит (за счет множественного разрешения столкновений в одном кадре) (7).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно добавить "силу тяжести", которая будет действовать если суммы сил векторов тяжести в точках соприкосновения (в вашем неправильном случае она одна, в правильном случае - две) не равна нулю. Если таковая есть, проверить чему она равна, и почему она получилась равная ноль.

Comment: Если опираться на картинки, то выглядит так, будто "шаг" движения слишком большой. В шаге N окружность еще не докатилась до второй линии, а на шаге N+1 уже пересекла ее. Поэтому остановится точно на линии невозможно. Возможно нужно уменьшить расстояние на которой окружность двигается за одну итерацию.

Comment: Вряд ли у тебя ещё на моменте картинки 2 было точное попадание в синюю линию - скорее всего, у тебя был там такой же "залёт", как на картинке 4 за красную. Однако этот первый "залёт" ты же скорректировал, переведя его в касание? ну так сделай то же и в момент на картинке 4...

Comment: Задача молекулярная или твёрдого тела? Или это будет чисто игра подобно "брось шар"?

Comment: nick_n_a, сила тяжести уже действует. Именно она тянет круг вниз.

Comment: Эникейщик, это игра. "Шар" может двигаться с любой скоростью. И при любой скорости будет момент, когда при проверке линия будет проходить сквозь круг. Akina, для картинки 4 скорректированная позиция - это картинка 5.  nick_n_a, это игра. Абсолютная точность не требуется. просто должно выглядеть более-менее реалистично.

Comment: *для картинки 4 скорректированная позиция - это картинка 5* Это - ОШИБКА. Поскольку шар "залетел", двигаясь по вектору с картинки 4, то сначала надо безусловно вернуть его по тому же вектору (ну, вернее, против этого вектора) до касания с линией, и только потом можно его смещать по вектору, нарисованному на картинке 5 (впрочем, второго смещения уже не потребуется, шарик-то "заклинило").

Comment: Akina, картинка 5 - это скорректированная позиция после возврата. Шар не просто вернулся в позицию касания с 1-ой линией, но и съехал чуть вниз-влево, т. к. его туда тянет сила тяжести и наклон линии. Это примерные построения. В игре просто видно, что шар докатился до позиции на рисунке и там застрял.

Answer (score 5):

Похоже, используется подход - каждый квант времени проверять, не случилось ли чего, и предпринимать какие-то действия (менять скорости и т.п.) . Но он далеко не всегда хорошо работает при расчёте столкновений и прочей кинематики.

Вместо этого лучше рассчитывать - какое событие случится в какой момент времени, и выполнять действия для самого раннего события.

```
 просчитать траекторию
 tau = Min(из событий, которые изменят траекторию)
 while (t < tau)
     осуществлять движение по траектории
     отрисовать кадр для времени t
     t++
 отрисовать кадр для времени tau (иначе может получится визуальный ляп)
 всё сначала
```

Получается, что не нужно обсчитывать столкновения часто. И редко не надо и вообще на регулярные расчеты  каждые n микросекунд не полагаемся. Только когда одно столкновение случается, тогда и обсчитывается движение до того, как последующее столкновение случится.

Comment: Так ведь для данной ситуации ничего не изменится: если провести симуляцию до начала реального движения - результат будет такой же как и сейчас. Если же выполнить действие только для одного события, то круг просто пройдет сквозь вторую линию. Или вы что-то другое имели ввиду?

Comment: Находим, что первое событие - касание линии 2 произойдет в момент t1. Считаем положение круга в этот момент, находим направление скатывания, начинаем новый отсчёт. Следующее событие - касание линии 1 в момент t2. Пройти сквозь линии при этом круг просто не может.

Comment: А как практически "пройтись" по этим моментам? Сейчас столкновения проверяются каждый кадр (60 раз в секунду). Например прямая линия проходит через Y5, шар двигается вертикально со скоростью 10 пикселей/кадр, позиция его края Y0. Сейчас алгоритм "сдвигает" шар, рассчитывает столкновения и потом уже обновляет позицию шара на экране. Т. е. во втором кадре позиция края Y10 и шар пересекает линию. Поэтому алгоритм "двигает" его в позицию Y5 и во втором кадре шар строго на линии. Вы предлагаете "двигать" шар и проверять столкновения 10 раз (для этого случая)?

Comment: Но ведь пересечение может находиться в дробных координатах. Даже если проверять столкновения 100 раз вместо 10-ти, этого может быть недостаточно и шар может все же пройти сквозь линию уже на экране.

Comment: Так же скорость может быть не постоянной, а изменяться, например, экспоненциально.

Comment: Да весь смысл предложенного метода в том, чтобы не проверять в заданные моменты и не допускать пролётов.

Comment: А когда именно проверять? Программа выполняется со скоростью 60 кадров в секунду. Т. е. нужно выполнять расчеты в каждом кадре, т. к. в следующем скорость может непредсказуемо измениться. Даже если сделать предсказание и узнать точку пересечения заранее, последующие расчеты в следующих кадрах все равно нужно сделать и рано или поздно окажется, что в данном кадре круг пересек линию.

Comment: Цикл изменения состояний выполняется независимо от "60 кадров". Вот косноязычная статья, иллюстрирующая некоторые моменты https://habr.com/post/136878/ Наверное, у игроделов можно найти и получше описание "игровой цикл аркады или платформера"

Comment: Не совсем ясно, как отвязывание обновлений мира игры от рендеринга исправит данную ситуацию. Даже если обсчитывать столкновения более часто или менее часто - это приведет к тому же результату после обновления экрана: при текущем алгоритме шар просто не может катиться дальше. В определенный момент линия 1 толкает шар в позицию пересечения с линией 2 вверх-вправо (это не отображается на экране - видны только состояния 1, 2 ,3 - другие рисунки просто иллюстрация процесса одного просчета столкновений). Линия 2 толкает шар вверх-влево. Просчет столкновений заканчивается и отображается кадр 3.

Comment: При следующем просчете шар опять движется вниз, снова пересекает линию 1 и цикл повторяется. Ситуация меняется только если плавно уменьшить силу гравитации до нуля или поочередно разрешать столкновения. В первом случае шар реалистично скатывается вниз (если скорость позволяет). Во втором - шар все же касается 1-ой линии, но его постоянно "болтает" на экране с явными проваливаниями в линии.

Comment: Похоже что проблема именно в последовательных просчетах. Линия 1 просто выталкивает шар вверх-вправо не учитывая линию 2. Может быть, сам подход неверный и есть алгоритм разрешающий все столкновения одновременно?

Answer (score 1):

*Мне непонятны направления синих стрелoк на рисунках 2, 4, 5 и 6. Это вектора скорости (или направления движения) круга - тогда они неправильные, или что-то другое?*

Точка, в которй будет находиться центр круга в момент касания обеих линий, находится как пересечение прямых параллельных линиям 1 и 2 и отстoящих от этих линий на расстояние равное радиусу круга.

Причем, все такие точки и, соответственно, соединяющие их отрезки, по которым может двигаться круг, можно найти заранее аналитически.

Comment: Синие стрелки - направление движения круга. На иллюстрация предположительного разрешения столкновений они нарисованы примерно. Это игра. Обычная практика для этого случая (в каком-то кадре круг гарантированно пересечет одну из линий) - разрешение столкновений после того как они произошли. И в данном случае разрешение столкновений происходит сразу же после их возникновения. Хотя круг и может коснуться 2+ линий одновременно, игра обработает их поочередно.

Comment: Т. е. в момент касания одной из линий ничего не известно о касании с другими. И лишь после перехода к следующей итерации цикла игра проверит другую линию. Кстати, если начать проверку со второй линии - ситуация выглядит зеркальной: круг зависает на первой линии не касаясь второй.

Comment: Какую очередность действий в каждом кадре вы предлагаете?

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо перейти от обсчёта времени к обсчёту событий.

Иными словами, вам *надо отказаться от покадровой проверки пересечений окружности* с прямыми, и вместо этого *определять* когда и через какой момент времени произойдёт *столкновение*, то есть точный момент пересечения непрерывной кривой-траектории с какой-нибудь из прямых. Всё, до этого момента мы можем ничего не делать и просто визуализировать движение окружности по этой траектории, рассчитаной при предыдущем столкновении. Причём визуализацию можно проводить с любой кадровой частотой, так как на физику мы никак при этом не влияем.

Когда же очередной кадр «перешагнёт» предсказанное событие, надо определить новую траекторию, получившуюся после этого события, и место следующего столкновения. Может так случиться, что между двумя соседними кадрами произойдёт больше одного столкновения (например, окружность с малой массой влетает в острый угол на большой скорости и начинает очень часто переотражаться). Поэтому определение и обработку событий надо производить в цикле перед собственно визуализацией текущего кадра, пока кадр по хронометражу вновь не начнёт отставать от очередного события — это событие и станет следующим.

К слову, в качестве события стоит взять момент пересечения окружностью очередной прямой в направлении снаружи внутрь. Это позволит окружности немного пролететь по инерции сквозь прямую, если она до этого имела большой импульс (мы же не можем согнуть прямую вслед за окружностью, так?).

Иными словами, событийная модель позволяет выполнять рассчёты только при смене траектории под влиянием внешних сил. Если столкновений мало, то частота пересчёта траектории будет значительно меньше кадровой частоты (FPS). Если же мы попадаем в плотную группу объектов — частота обработки событий начинает значительно превышать кадровую. При этом скачки FPS не влияют на точность физики.

Теперь перейдём к определению траектории после очередного столкновения. Так как при столкновении окружности придаётся ускорение, то траектория будет представлять собой кривую вида *p = p<sub>0</sub>t<sub>loc</sub> + v<sub>0</sub>t<sub>loc</sub> + (a<sup>2</sup> / 2)t<sub>loc</sub>*, где:

- *p* — точка на траектории в определённый момент времени. Является вектором, то есть парой координат (*x* и *y*).
- *p<sub>0</sub>* — точка столкновения, от которой и пошла текущая траектория.
- *v<sub>0</sub>*, *a* — скорость и ускорение окружности, получившиеся после его соударения с прямой. Также являются векторами. Так как событие попадает точно на момент соударения с поверхностью, нам не надо непрерывно симулировать выталкивание окружности из этой поверхности. Просто пересчитываем ускорение с учётом направления переотражения и гравитации. И да, стоит также учитывать упругость (т. е. поглощение энергии), чтобы окружность не скакала постоянно по сцене. Скорость при этом берём ту, какая была на момент пересечения точки *x<sub>0</sub>*.
- *t<sub>loc</sub>* — относительная временна́я отметка. Считается в секундах виртуального мира, отсчитывается от момента нахождения в точке *x<sub>0</sub>*.

Однако данный подход хорош только при единомоментных соударениях. Что же делать при скольжении по прямой, когда окружность постоянно стремится уйти под поверхность? Тут, увы, придётся пожертвовать реалистичностью (которая, впрочем, вам и так не важна), чтобы не считать эффекты, связанные с упругими микроотскоками. Также уберём вращение окружности (т. е. как бы сделаем прямые идеально скользкими). Тогда получится, что окружность честно сделает первые несколько отскоков, которые благодаря упругости относительно быстро сойдутся к нулю, а затем просто начнёт скользить.

И чтобы у нас действительно было скольжение (без событий пересечения), необходимо перед определением дальнейшей траектории проверять скорость вдоль перпендикуляра к прямой-поверхности. Если скорость не превышает некий малый порог (так как абсолютного нуля мы никогда не достигнем), значит при расчёте траектории направляем ускорение в нижнюю часть сцены вдоль прямой. В противном случае переходим к обработке соударения.

При этом стоит дополнительно проверить, не закончится ли эта прямая раньше, чем произойдёт какое-то пересечение. Если да, то в качестве следующего события берём не соударение, а соскок с поверхности, во время которого надо заменить вектор ускорения на ускорение свободного падения. Без этого сфера продолжит скользить по поверхности, которая уже закончилась.

Comment: "и вместо этого определять когда и через какой момент времени произойдёт столкновение". Исправит ли эта новая модель текущую ситуацию? Ведь даже если не "выталкивать", а "ставить" круг в точную позицию на линию, рано или поздно возникнет момент, изображенный на рисунке 5: круг точно на одной прямой, но чуть провалился в другую, т. к. алгоритм, "ставящий" круг на прямую, ничего не знает о другой прямой в этот момент. И в итоге круг зависнет как на рисунке 3. Даже если все просчитать один раз в момент начала движения и потом просто показывать покадровую анимацию.